# Possible to change encode options for each low search form?

Tags: expresso-store, low-search

I was able to use low search to filter entries, by getting the values of the parameters in the URL, I set No for encode query setting in the low search module.

I set it back to Yes to and tested my sitewide search form, which it needs to be encoded.

is there an encode parameter in the form tag that I can set on the fly?

If I could get this (below) to work using the query="{segment_2}" then I won't need to set the encode setting on the fly:

```
<select name="store:price">
    <option value="0">PRICE</option>
    <option value="|10"{if get:price == "|10"} selected{/if}>up to $10</option>
    <option value="10|25"{if get:price == "10|25"} selected{/if}>$10 to $25</option>
    <option value="25|50"{if get:price == "25|50"} selected{/if}>$25 to $50</option>
    <option value="50|100"{if get:price == "50|100"} selected{/if}>$50 to $100</option>
    <option value="100|"{if get:price == "100|"} selected{/if}>$100 and up</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now, the Encode Query setting in Low Search is installation-wide.

However, with the right setup, you should be able to run all searches with the same setting. I can't think of a reason why you'd want one search encoded and not another.

---

To have the price option selected in the Form tag when encoding queries, use the following code:

```
{exp:low_search:form query="{segment_x}"}
    <select name="store:price">
        <option value="">PRICE</option>
        <option value="|10"{if low_search_store:price == "|10"} selected{/if}>up to $10</option>
        <option value="10|25"{if low_search_store:price == "10|25"} selected{/if}>$10 to $25</option>
        ...
    </select>
{/exp:low_search:form}
```

Make sure `{segment_x}` points to the encoded query in the URI. If you're not encoding queries, you can use the exact same code, and remove the `query` parameter.

Note that [the principle of parameter names and corresponding variables](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search/docs/parameters#params) applies here just as it does for any other filter.

Comment: I am fine with using it with encoding enabled, but I need to set the select option if this value then set it to selected, look at the html I have above and that should give you an idea of what I need to accomplish.

Comment: See my edit. Does that help?